# Sublime Text 2 Project Settings Not Overriding Default?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have the following `sublime-project` file in my top-most directory but it is not overriding my default settings.  The `tab_size` defaults to 4 for instance.  Am I doing something wrong?

```
{
  "settings":
  {
    "tab_size": 2,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": false,
    "trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true,
    "default_line_ending": "unix"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to go to `Project -> Save Project As -> Save`.

I named it myProject and it created two files:

- `myProject.sublime-workspace`
- `myProject.sublime-project`

Editing `myProject.sublime-project` now overrides defaults across the project.